# Stream raspicam_node using RAW Image

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi3, ros

Any idea how to enable raw when using raspicam_node?

i always stream the image topic under the address `/raspicam_node/image/compressed`.
How can i change the topic into `/raspicam_node/image`?

i have try some solution by type
`roslaunch raspicam_node camerav2_1280x720.launch enable_raw:=true`
and the parameter says that `/raspicam_node/enable_raw: True`
but went i try to subscribe under the topic `/raspicam_node/image`,
the terminal says `Unable to convert 'bgr8' image for display: 'Image is wrongly formed: height * step != size or 960 * 3840 != 1843200`

any one have the common problem to solve this one?

Comment: How are you trying to subscribe to it?

Comment: its not a code, its a launch file provide by [Ubiquity](https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node)

Comment: If you're using one of their launch files my first thought is exactly what the error says. Your camera not outputting the resolution given by the ros params.

Comment: i thought i must change the driver and launch files from another source